# Wikipedia in the builtin dictionary in hebrew...but only when searching for tech words?

Tags: macos, dictionary

It doesn't do it for all of them, ex. when I search TCP/IP it's in english but a search for BSD yields this

> Berkeley Software Distribution, או בקיצור BSD, היא מערכת הפעלה נגזרת של מערכת ההפעלה UNIX, שנוצרה ותוחזקה באוניברסיטת קליפורניה בברקלי מאז שנות ה-70 עד לאמצע שנות התשעים של המאה העשרים. כיום, המושג 'BSD' מתייחס לאחד מצאצאי BSD המקורי, הווה אומר מערכות FreeBSD, NetBSD או OpenBSD, שגם הן מערכות דמויות UNIX.

אחד הרכיבים של מערכת Mac OS X הוא Darwin, שהיא ליבת מערכת שמבוססת על FreeBSD.

I have already checked in preferences and english is the only language selected. I'm running 10.10.2 on a late 2013 Macbook Pro 15. Does anyone know what is causing certain ones to be in hebrew when I want only english and how to fix it?

Comment: do you want it in Hebrew or not ?

Comment: No, I do not want it in Hebrew.

Comment: Which preferences did you check in? Under Dictionary Preferences, if you click on Wikipedia in the list of sources, you'll get a checklist of all of the languages you want. Make sure Hebrew's unchecked there. Also, assuming Hebrew was selected, the reason why it happened for BSD was because there's no article called "BSD" in English (the page is called Berkeley Software Distribution). I just did a search for BSD after making sure it was in English, and the result was a disambiguation page. It probably decided that the Hebrew BSD article is better than the English disambiguation page.

Comment: That was exactly the problem/solution! If you turn that into an answer, I will mark it check it off. I don't know why I didn't think to click on the actual word, I usually do that accidentally when trying to click the box.